# no space left on device error for /boot

Tags: apt, partitioning

I have a 237MB `/boot` partition which I thought should be enough for normal operation, however, when I do a `apt-get upgrade` I get the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for ron: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.2.0-16 linux-headers-4.2.0-16-generic linux-headers-4.2.0-27
  linux-headers-4.2.0-27-generic linux-image-4.2.0-16-generic
  linux-image-4.2.0-27-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-16-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-27-generic linux-signed-image-4.2.0-27-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.120ubuntu6) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.120ubuntu6) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-34-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-34-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
$
```

and that while:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           384M  6.2M  378M   2% /run
/dev/dm-0       454G  9.8G  421G   3% /
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2       237M  209M   16M  93% /boot
/dev/sda1       511M  3.4M  508M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           384M  8.0K  384M   1% /run/user/1000
$
```

Comment: Have you 'apt-get autoremove' to see if the space that's cleared is enough to continue?

Comment: @kos if you move your comment into an answer, I can accept it as resolved!

Comment: You should have a "Yes, this solved my problem!" (or similar) button which you can click to "accept" the closure, can you see it?

Comment: @kos, you can't accept a comment as an answer, I think that's why he was suggesting you move it to an answer.

Comment: @Brian and cerr, please see [here](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/close-questions) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250981/302251)